# How to set condition in Query Builder?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to set a condition in my function where I need set my column `role_id` equal to 1 if it's true it will return me a view. First I retrieve all the column in my `users` table `$result = DB::table('users')->get();` after that I set a if condition.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Http\Requests;
use DB;

class DocumentController extends Controller
{
    public function getDocuments()
    {
        $result = DB::table('users')->get();


        if ('role_id' == 1)
        {
            return view ('document.create');
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to set my `role_id == 1` but it says.

> Use of undefined constant role_id - assumed 'role_id'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check the current user, you just need to take advantage of `Auth::user()`:

```
 if(\Auth::user()->role_id == 1)
```

Comment: How to set condition if `role_id` is more than one?

Comment: How is it defined if it's more than one? `1,2,3`, `1|2|3`, or some other way?

Comment: Instead of writing `else if (Auth::user()->role_id == 3)` how can I do this in one condition?

Comment: You want both to show that view?` if(\Auth::user()->role_id == 1 || Auth::user()->role_id == 3)`. If you want them to go to different views, then you'll need an if/else or a switch statement.

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
// if you want to fetch only user with role_id = 1
    $users = DB::table('users')->where('role_id', '=', 1)->get();
```

in your case you can use condition like

```
if( $users->role_id == 1 )
{

}
```

Comment: This shows me a the view. But when I login user with different `role_id` it still show me the `return view ('document.create');` Assuming that this view is only applicable for `role_id` that has a value of 1.

Comment: if you are checking the login user only then you have to use like  if(\Auth::user()->role_id == 1)  @anyber suggested.

Comment: Exactly that's what I'm looking for. Appreciated your help.